# Pass props to child objects in array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-props, array.prototype.map

My application routes are an array that is mapped inside `<Router>` which seems to be a common approach. I want to pass some extra props to the `<Component />`. When I explicitly name the prop, it is passed to `<Component />` and I can use it, however, when I spread the props, it is undefined in the `<Component />`.

I need to spread the props because I want to pass through other props in the future and don't want to explicitly name all the props in App.js.

How can I ensure `<Component />` receives props from ``routes``` without naming the props explicitly?

My code:

When I spread the props, they won't pass to the child component:

```
const routes = [
    {
      type: PublicRoute,
      path: "/login",
      component: LoginForm,
      register: true, // I want to pass this prop
    }
  ]
  
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => {
            const RouteType = route.type;
            const Component = route.component;
            const Dashboard = dashboard;
            return (
            <Route
                key={i}
                path={route.path}
                exact
                render={(props) => (
                <RouteType role={route.role}>
                    <Dashboard>
                      <Component {...props} /> // register not passed
                    </Dashboard>
                </RouteType>
                )}
            />
            );
        })}
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

If I name the prop (register), it passes to the child component fine:

```
const routes = [
    {
      type: PublicRoute,
      path: "/login",
      component: LoginForm,
      register: true, // I want to pass this prop
    }
  ]

<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => {
            const RouteType = route.type || Fragment;
            const Component = route.component;
            const Dashboard = dashboard;
            return (
            <Route
                key={i}
                path={route.path}
                exact
                render={(props) => (
                <RouteType role={route.role}>
                    <Dashboard>
                      <Component register={route.register} /> // register is passed ok
                    </Dashboard>
                </RouteType>
                )}
            />
            );
        })}
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass like this.

```
<Component {...route, ...props} />
```

Comment: Thanks @Amruth <Component {...route, ...props} /> threw an error but <Component {...route} /> worked fine. So simple, I can't believe I missed this. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah may be you need to use Object.assign, but am glad that it helped you :)